# How do I calculate the length (exclude escape codes) of a string containing ANSI colour codes

Tags: jq

### Current

I am unable to calculate the length of a string containing ANSI colour codes.

The snippet below shows that the 'length' of the string is 10.

### Expected

Since the string only has the letter "a" in it, I would like to have some function that determines the length of the string to be 1.

```
def escape: "\u001b";
def _red(text):
  escape + "[31m" + text + escape + "[0m";
_red("a") | length # gives 10
```

### Background

To provide a bit more context I have a left pad function in jq that relies on the length of the string to determine how much to pad a provided string with. However, this padding function does not work if the provided string contains ANSI colour codes.

```
def lp($len):
  if . == null then "" else . end | tostring | ($len - length) as $l | (" " * $l)[:$l] + .;
```

Comment: Do you want to ignore ANSI escape sequences? Because, you know, technically they are part of the string and thus contribute to the string's length

Comment: Note that `if . == null then "" else . end` can probably be shortened to `. // ""`. And what is `(" " * $l)[:$l]` supposed to do? It already is of length `$l`, you don't need to slice it to length `$l` again; that's redundant.

Comment: thanks for the tips, I copied this script from somewhere a long time ago, now might be a good time to clean it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the regular expression from the Superuser question [Removing ANSI color codes from text stream](https://superuser.com/q/380772/3773):

```
def escape: "\u001b";
def _red(text):
  escape + "[31m" + text + escape + "[0m";
def _strip_ansi: gsub("\\x1b\\[[0-9;]*m"; "");
_red("a") | _strip_ansi | length # gives 1
```